# Add data to specific object property with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, indexing

I have an object that looks like this:

```
imgs: {
    img1: {
        on: 0,
        scr: null
    },
    img2: {
        on: 0,
        scr: null
    },
    and so on...
}
```

What I want is to use the index of a clicked image to reach the specific image property in the object.

**js:**

```
MoveUpImg: function(index) {

    Capsule.imgs['img' + index].on = 1;

    // rest of the code
},
```

This code doesn't work:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'on' of undefined
```

By changing to a specific object property, let's say img2 it works:

```
Capsule.imgs.img2.on = 1;
```

...this means that it's something with this line that's the problem:

```
Capsule.imgs['img' + index].on = 1;
```

(of course I've checked that index gives me the correct number and so on)

Comment: Best guess -- with an array

Comment: @blgt: Of course that would be possible, but I want to use an object instead by several reasons.

Comment: What happens, you say it "doesn't work"? How is `imgs` related to `MoveUpImg` w.r.t. the code, are they both contained in the same namespace? Can you produce a simplified jsFiddle of your problem?

Comment: And if you log the value of `index` when the function is called, what does it show?

Comment: Please provide us with a simplified jsFiddle or more of the surrounding code, like http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jR7ur/ This is working.

Comment: Well accessing with `someObject["someString"]` does exactly the same as `someObject.someString`. You're likely going over the amount of your `img#`s. Try sticking in a `if( ('img'+index) in imgs )` condition check

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `img` to function but try to access the `imgs` object

Should be

```
MoveUpImg: function(imgs, index) {
```

instead of

```
MoveUpImg: function(img, index) {
```

Comment: I wasn't clear about that part. 'img' that is passed to the function is a completely different variable that's used for some other code in the function. The 'imgs' object however is accessed globally within the js code (i use object literal).

Comment: Then there must the problem around `Capsule.imgs['img'...`, other codes are fine http://jsfiddle.net/824Ge/1/

Comment: What the result will come if you put `Capsule.imgs['img1'].on = 1;`?